# select string by negative lookahead?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this structure :

`[digit][\w+][\#]`

The `#` is not mandatory.

examples : *(1 is the digit , just for simplicity)*

- `1bbbb#`
- `1bbbb`

It can also repeat itself :

`1bbbb#1cccccc`

Question :

I want to get all the chars who do not have at future  chars ,  the `#` char.

examples :

- `1bbbb#` -- zero results ( becuase there is `#` at future chars)
- `1bbbb` -- wanted result : `1bbbb`
- `1bbbb#1cccccc` -- wanted result : `1cccccc`
- `1bbbb#1cccccc#1kkk` -- wanted result : `1kkk`

What have I tried :

`1(?!.+\#)`

but this return (obviously) only the first char of the desired result:

[image]

Any help ?  (http://regexr.com?3783k)

*(I would love to see a negative lookahead solution).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
1\w+(?!.*\#)
```

`1bbbb` matches `1bbbb`

`1bbbb#` no results

`1bbbb#1ccccccc` matches `1ccccccc`

`1bbbb#1ccccccc#` no results

`1bbbb#1ccccccc#1kkkkkkk` matches `1kkkkkkk`

Comment: Not really, `1bbbb1cccccc` matches `1bbbb1cccccc`, while, as far as I understand, it should give `1bbbb` AND `1cccccc`.

Comment: @Max no. As I said , it can repeat itself and `#` is not mandatory.